# Frequency-dependent interaction will be retarded in time

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, field-theory

In condensed matter physics, I often heard that **Frequency-dependent interaction will be retarded in time**. I don't quite understand this statement. Can anyone give me some arguments or references? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just a statement about Fourier transforms. The FT of a constant is a delta-function in time. The FT of a non-trivial function of frequency is a non trivial function of t-t'.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that since causality holds, all time-dependent interactions must be retarded in time. Therefore, the statement in bold is really saying that frequency-dependent interactions correspond to time-dependent interactions. Phrased this way, the statement is quite trivial, since one can Fourier transform between time and frequency.

Let's get some intuition by considering the simplest interaction we can think of, $V(\omega) = g$, where $g$ is some constant. A Fourier transform yields $V(t) = g\delta(t)$. That is, our interaction is instantaneous in time. This is the situation one is used to: two particles repel/attract as a function of, say, their relative positions, at some moment in time. (Assume that we are in the non-relativistic limit.)

Now, how would a frequency-dependent interaction arise? The prototypical example in condensed matter, at least, is that of the phonon-mediated electron-electron interaction. Let's first think of this from a non-mathematical point of view. Consider an electron which is zooming through a solid, which we can think of a set of heavy, postively-charged ions. As the electron zooms by some ions, these positive ions are pulled toward the electron. This ionic movement is slow (relative to electronic timescales), since ions are heavier than the electrons. Therefore, some time later, after the electron is long gone, the positive ions are still distorted from their equilibrium positions. This ionic distortion leads to a potential which attracts electrons. That is, other electrons are attracted to where the first electron was! This time-delay, coming from the slow ionic movement, is why one can think of this interaction as being retarded in nature.

In summary, we have just described a process where the electron-ion interaction leads to an effective electron-electron interaction which is  retarded in time.

As for handling this mathematically, you may want to check out "Methods of Quantum Field Theory in Statistical Mechanics" by Abrikosov, Gorkov, and Dzyaloshinskii, or "Superconductivity" by Schrieffer. There's a problem in "Condensed Matter Field Theory" by Altland and Simons using the path-integral formulation which also goes over this somewhat. I'm sure there are plenty of other textbooks which are helpful in this regard. In short, assuming you know standard QFT, recall how photon propagators appear in QED. You have some interaction coupling the electromagnetic field $A_\mu$, to your electron field $\psi$, $H_\mathrm{int} \sim \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi A_\mu$. This coupling leads to effective interactions between the electrons which begin at second order in $A_\mu$, due to contractions of the type $\langle A_\mu A_\nu\rangle$. This contraction/photon Green's function has some frequency dependence. Since this contraction is essentially your effective electron-electron interaction, your effective interaction is also frequency-dependent.

My earlier example regarding the phonon-mediated electron-electron interaction is essentially the same as this, but with $A_\mu$ replaced by the distortion field $\phi$ (see the recommended textbooks for details.) The frequency dependence of this interaction comes from the frequency dependence of the phonon Green's function.

Of course, the interaction need not be phonon-mediated. However, this is the most intuitive example, in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe you give some intuitions. But just from intuition, I don't know anything quantitatively,  for example which part of frequency corresponds highly retarded interaction, and which part corresponds to slightly retarded interation. Thanks for your references.

Comment: Low frequencies corresponds to long time scales, while high frequencies correspond to short time scales. Oh, another reference which goes over phonon-mediated interactions which you may want to look into is "Many-Particle Physics" by Mahan.